# php string to integer conversion and comparison

Tags: php, string, integer, comparison, operator-keyword

I'm somewhat confused and was hoping you guys could help. I'm writing something simple that takes a value from the posted name field and returns it, checking to see beforehand that its a string(correct) or an integer(in which case it'll say 'a name is not a number').

```
<?php

$number = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");

if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<p>Enter your name</p>
<form method="post" action="action4.php">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
}else{
$name = $_POST['name'];
foreach($number as $v){
$int = (int)$v;
}
if($name == $int){
    print "This is a number and not a name.";
}else{
            print $name;
   }
}
?>
```

Given that every number entered into the name field was seen as a string, I cycled through the array and converted every digit to an integer. When entering an integer into the name field however, rather than getting "this is a number and not a name" I get $name. Reciprocally if I enter in a string, I get "this is a number and not a name."

var_dumping both name and int in the if statement returns as expected: $name as string and $int as integer. So why are they comparing as true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are doing nothing but assigning a variable in your `foreach` loop the final value of `$v` is `0`. When PHP compares strings to integers it converts the string to an integer to do the comparison (see Type Juggling). So `$name` becomes `0`. `0` equals `0` so your if statement is always true.

To overcome this you need to compare variable *type* and *value* (and do your comparison inside your `foreach` loop). This means using the `===` comparison operator which compares both type and value as opposed to just value which is what `==` does.

Reference: [Comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), [Type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: The second part of that was easy to understand but in reference to the first half are you saying that once outside the foreach statement $int just reads as 0?

Comment: If you wan't to make sure no digits in the input, regular expression would do. e.g. preg_match('/\d/', $name) will return a positive value if it found a digit in $name.

Comment: Yes, take a close look at your loop. It just overwrites `$v` leaving its value as the last value of that array which is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `===` to compare the types and values of variables. If you use `==` php will automatically convert both values before comparing them.

But to check that the inputs aren't integers, it should be enough to test with [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric).